# AWS Amplify lambda function timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

My lambda function always timeouts with `504` when called from my app code, but tests on the function from the AWS console work fine.  I've tried a number of approaches to no effect. I've also tried using an axios intercepter to increase the timeout on all requests in the code as some suggested, but it didn't work either, and I also don't want it on all requests from the app, just this particular endpoint.

Cloudwatch log from catch error in lambda:

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 504",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 900000,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "User-Agent": "axios/0.27.2",
            "Content-Length": 2844
        },
        "url": "https://api.endpoint.com/",
        "method": "post",
        "data": "{/"payload": { ...payload }}"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE",
    "status": 504
}
```

I've increased the memory and timeout configuration on the function settings in the console.

I've tried increasing the timeout property locally and pushing up to the cloud in `./amplify/backend/function/my-function/my-function-cloudformation-template.json`.

I've added timeout property to the request in the code:

```js
import { API } from 'aws-amplify'

await API.post('my-api', '/my-path', { body: payload, timeout: 15 * 60 * 1000 })
```

I've also added the timeout property to the axios request in the lambda function.

```js
/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
*/

const axios = require('axios')

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const parsedBody = JSON.parse(event.body)
  try {
    const out = await axios({
      url: 'https://www.api.endpoint.com/',
      method: 'post',
      data: { data: parsedBody },
      timeout: 15 * 60 * 1000
    })
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(out.data),
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', JSON.stringify(error)),
    return {
      statusCode: error.statusCode || 500,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try checking the `Lambda` logs in `Cloudwatch`? You will get a detailed report for each invocation there. You might just get your clue.

Comment: Yes I did, it gives me `message: "Request failed with status code 504"`, `name: "AxiosError"`, `status: 504` , `code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"`.  I've added the full log to the question.